# Is there anyway to correct from this (blue) screen?

Tags: bsod, templeos

I'm just not sure, but is this the equivalent of the [Blue Screen of Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death) for TempleOS or is there a way to recover from this?

[image: Temple Blue Screen of Death]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the wallpaper with the ["Adam Task" (TempleOS version of `init`) at the top from `Glossary.DD.Z`](https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Doc/Glossary.html),

> This is Adam, as in Adam and Eve, the parent of all tasks.  Adam is immortal. The adam task is created at start-up and appears in the small window at the top beneath the user terminal windows.  Since the Adam task is immortal, on Adam's heap go all memory objects which you don't want destroyed by any single task's death.  When created, Adam runs the file `::/StartOS.HC`.  When start-up is finished, the adam task enters a server mode where it accepts requests from other tasks.  The `Adam("")` routine will make Adam compile and run text src code.  `#include stmts` can be sent to `Adam("")`, creating system-wide code and data which are immortal.

To spawn a new terminal window, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> or click the blinking "Term" button in the bottom right hand corner of the screen.

(Thanks to [Alec Murphy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9760788/alec-murphy) for the pointer)